How to sort pairs of columns in R while keeping associated values together
I'm trying to create a ranked table where I need to sort each pair of columns by the second column in each pair. The first column in each pair needs to stay with its corresponding value. How can I do this in a concise/easy way?
df <- data.frame(
  State1 = c("Ak", "Al", "Az"),
  Value1 = c(1, 10, 30),
  State2 = c("Ak", "Al", "Az"),
  Value2 = c(45, 3, 20))


I want the final output to look like this:
  State1 Value1 State2 Value2
      Az     30     Ak     45
      Al     10     Az     20
      Ak      1     Al      3



This looks like two separate dataframes, why are they together?

Typically the items in each row of a data frame are semantically linked, so I'm not sure there is an easy way. library(dplyr); bind_cols( df |> select(1:2) |> arrange(-Value1),  df |> select(3:4) |> arrange(-Value2))

Here's a solution in base without the need of creating "helper" variables; basically, I slice the dataframe for each pair, then sort each slice based on the 2nd column, i.e. Value#, and then I join the sorted dataframes together.
lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by=2), \(i) df[i:min((i+1), ncol(df))]) |>
  lapply(\(d) d[order(d[,2], decreasing = TRUE), ]) |>
  cbind.data.frame()

#>   State1 Value1 State2 Value2
#> 3     Az     30     Ak     45
#> 2     Al     10     Az     20
#> 1     Ak      1     Al      3


A hack would be to first split the data frames into two, reorder their numeric columns, and then merge them back into one data frame like so:
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  State1 = c("Ak", "Al", "Az"),
  Value1 = c(1, 10, 30),
  State2 = c("Ak", "Al", "Az"),
  Value2 = c(45, 3, 20))

df1 <- df[,c("State1","Value1")]


df2 <- df[,c("State2","Value2")]

df1 <- df1 |> 
  arrange(desc(Value1))

df2 <- df2 |> 
  arrange(desc(Value2))


df_merge <- cbind(df1,df2)


df_merge

  State1 Value1 State2 Value2
1     Az     30     Ak     45
2     Al     10     Az     20
3     Ak      1     Al      3

Hope this helps!

A base solution:
df |> 
  split.default(ceiling(seq_along(df) / 2)) |> # slice after every second column
  lapply(\(x) x[order(-x[, 2]),]) |>           # order by the second column
  unname() |>                                  # drop list names
  data.frame()                                 # convert back to data frame

#  State1 Value1 State2 Value2
#3     Az     30     Ak     45
#2     Al     10     Az     20
#1     Ak      1     Al      3


library(purrr)
library(tibble)

split.default(df, rep(1:2, each = ncol(df) %/% 2)) |>
  map_dfc(\(x) enframe(sort(deframe(x), decreasing = T))) |>
  set_names(names(df))

This iterates over columns two at a time, turns that data frame into a named vector where the State is the name and Value is the value, sorts this vector in decreasing order, converts it back into a data frame, and then combines them column-wise.

Make use of sort_by from base R > 4.4
unname(split.default(df, gsub("\\D", "", names(df)))) |>
   lapply(\(y)sort_by(y, -y[[2]]))|>
   cbind.data.frame()

  State1 Value1 State2 Value2
3     Az     30     Ak     45
2     Al     10     Az     20
1     Ak      1     Al      3

